# parse_vt_settings /dev/tty0 (permission denied)

Tags: raspberry-pi, xorg

I am trying to run **xinit chromium-browser some_settings address:port** in /home/pi/.bashrc file.

What it does in first version of "Jessie PIXEL" is open chromium browser on start up after console auto-login and opens the page address:port.

In new version of Jessie PIXEL I get the following error:

> [   513.403] 
>  X.Org X Server 1.18.4
>  Release Date:
>   2016-07-19< [   513.403] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
>  [
>   513.403] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.26-v7+ armv7l Raspbian
>  [   513.403] Current Operating System: Linux raspberrypi 4.4.38-v7+
>   !!938 SMP Thu Dec 15 15:22:21 GMT 2016 armv7l
>  [   513.403] Kernel command line: 8250.nr_uarts=1 dma.dmachans=0x7f35
>   bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=1920 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=1080
>   bcm2709.boardrev=0x2a02082 bcm2709.serial=0xff00$
>  [   513.403]
>   Build Date: 11 November 2016  11:59:59AM
>  [   513.403] xorg-server
>   2:1.18.4-2+rpi1 (https://www.debian.org/support)
>  [   513.403]
>   Current version of pixman: 0.33.3
>  [   513.403]    Before
>   reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
>           to make sure that you have the latest version.
>  [   513.403] Markers: (--) probed, (*) from config file, (==) default setting,
>           (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
>           (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
>  [   513.403] (==) Log file:
>   "/home/pi/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Dec 23 09:46:08
>   2016
>  [   513.404] (==) Using system config directory
>   "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
>  [   513.404] (==) No Layout section.
>   Using the first Screen section.
>  [   513.404] (==) No screen
>   section available. Using defaults.
>  [   513.405] (*) |-->Screen
>   "Default Screen Section" (0)
>  [   513.405] (*) |   |-->Monitor
>   ""
>  [   513.405] (==) No device specified for
>   screen "Default Screen Section".
>           Using the first device section listed.
>  [   513.405] (*) |   |-->Device "Allwinner A10/A13 FBDEV"
>  [   513.405] (==) No monitor
>   specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
>           Using a default monitor configuration.
>  [   513.405] (==) Automatically adding devices
>  [   513.405] (==) Automatically
>   enabling devices
>  [   513.405] (==) Automatically adding GPU
>   devices
>  [   513.405] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource
>   mask: 0x1fffff
>  [   513.405] (WW) The directory
>   "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc" does not exist.
>  [   513.405]    Entry
>   deleted from font path.
>  [   513.405] (WW) The directory
>   "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
>  [   513.405]
>   Entry deleted from font path.
>  [   513.405] (WW) The directory
>   "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
>  [   513.405]
>   Entry deleted from font path.
>  [   513.405] (WW) The directory
>   "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
>  [   513.405]
>   Entry deleted from font path.
>  [   513.405] (==) FontPath set
>   to:
>           /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
>           /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
>           /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
>           built-ins
>  [   513.405] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
>  [   513.405] (II) The server relies on
>   udev to provide the list of input devices.
>           If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
>  [   513.406] (II) Loader magic: 0x54d5cf20
>  [
>   513.406] (II) Module ABI versions:
>  [   513.406]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
>  [   513.406]    X.Org Video Driver: 20.0
>  [
>   513.406]    X.Org XInput driver : 22.1
>  [   513.406]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
>  [   513.411] (II) systemd-logind: took
>   control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/c2
>  [
>   513.411] (II) no primary bus or device found
>  [   513.411] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
>  [   513.412] (II) Loading
>   /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
>  [   513.416] (II)
>   Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
>  [   513.416]    compiled
>   for 1.18.4, module version = 1.0.0
>  [   513.416]    ABI class:
>   X.Org Server Extension, version 9.0
>  [   513.416] (==) AIGLX
>   enabled
>  [   513.416] (II) LoadModule: "fbturbo"
>  [   513.416]
>   (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbturbo_drv.so
>  [
>   513.417] (II) Module fbturbo: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
>  [   513.417]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 0.5.1
>  [   513.417]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
>  [   513.417]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
>  [   513.417] (II)
>   FBTURBO: driver for framebuffer: fbturbo
>  [   513.417] (EE)
>   Fatal server error:
>  [   513.417] (EE) parse_vt_settings: Cannot
>   open /dev/tty0 (Permission denied)
>  [   513.417] (EE)
>  [
>   513.417] (EE)
>  Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
>            at http://wiki.x.org for help.
>  [   513.417] (EE) Please also check the log file at
>   
> "/home/pi/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional
>   information.
>  [   513.417] (EE)
>  [   513.418] (WW)
>   xf86CloseConsole: KDSETMODE failed: Bad file descriptor
>  [
>   513.418] (WW) xf86CloseConsole: VT_GETMODE failed: Bad file descriptor
>  [   513.419] (EE) Server terminated with error (1).
>   Closing log file.

Does anybody know where lies the problem?

PS If You see '*' in the log it was '**' but that is bold text
Also there is '!!' in log that was '#' but thats bold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same issue.
How I solve this was:

1. create new user named teacher
2. grant all groups that pi has
3. cp the /etc/suders.d/010_pi-nopasswd and rename the inner username to teacher
4. startx and it works.

Be careful:
don't run startx in byobu, some bugs.

Answer (score 6):

In particular, you want to add your user to the tty group to resolve this specific issue.

```
gpasswd -a pi tty
```

where pi is your user.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

I don't use .bashrc anymore and I fully moved to rc.local.

```
sudo node /home/pi/server/server.js &

xinit /usr/bin/chromium-browser --no-sandbox --window-size=1920,1080 --noerrdialogs --start-fullscreen --start-maximized --disable-notifications --disable-infobars --kiosk --incognito http://localhost:3000 -- -nocursor &

exit 0
```

What this does is runs node.js server on port 3000 and runs chromium on localhost:3000 with no mouse cursor and fully sized chromium browser in something like 15-20 sec time.

**Now working on showing it without going blank. Still no success, HELP!**

EDIT:
If chromium appears with borders use this:

```
xinit /usr/bin/chromium-browser --no-sandbox --window-position=0,0 --window-size=1920,1080 --noerrdialogs --disable-notifications --disable-infobars --kiosk --incognito http://localhost:3000 -- -nocursor &
```